# How do I get the temperature of a stainless steel pipe that's being heated by a direct current?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, thermodynamics, heat-transfer, convection

I'm working on the following problem:

> Use a stainless-steel pipe with an internal diameter of 0.016m and a length of 2.5 m to conduct a convective heat transfer experiment. During the experiment, the stainless-steel tube is directly heated by direct current with a voltage of 5V and current of 900A, and the inlet temperature of the water is 20°C. The flow velocity is 0.5 m/s, the pipe is insulated externally, and the heat loss is ignored. Find the surface heat transfer coefficient and the temperature difference of the convective heat transfer in the tube.

Since there is no width of the pipe, I can't use the specific heat of stainless steel to figure out the temperature of the pipe. I resorted to calculating the added temperature through the water's specific heat, and got 30.7 °C as the outlet temperature, but I'm not confident in this solution at all.

How should I go about it?
Thanks in advance.

Edited to add my calculations:
I used the Joule heating formula [image]. Then, I divided Q by the specific heat capacity per the mass of water, so [image]. The result was 10.69°C, so it would be 30.69°C for the final temperature.

I wasn't sure if this was the correct way to go about this, since the problem seems to stress on the stainless-steel bit, so I was wondering if there is another way to do this more accurately.

Comment: It's been a **long time** since I've done anything like this, but ... electrical power, P=IV. In your case P=  5(900)=4500 W. As a starting point I'd assume this would be the heat energy provided by the electrical heater & that this gets added to the 20C inlet water temperature. Finish it off.

Comment: Can you [Edit] to show your calculations? I'm getting more like a 10°C temperature rise.

Comment: @Fred, thank you, I did go that route with my solution, just wasn't quite sure about it

Comment: @Transistor Edited, sorry I might've been a bit unclear, the rise I got was 10°C as well, 30°C was the overall outlet water temperature so 10° + the inlet 20°

Comment: Attach a thermocouple.

Comment: @blacksmith37 Just a theoretical problem unfortunately :/

Comment: For the heat transfer coefficient, you may need to consider gradual change of the fluid (and possibly also wall) temperature along the pipe.

Comment: @TomášLétal I attempted to do that by calculating the logarithmic mean temperature difference so I could plug it into the Q=h×A×LMTD formula, but I didn't manage to. As for the pipe wall, I figured that in a stable condition of the system, the pipe's temperature would be 20°C (from the water)+10.7°C (from the current), so a constant 30.7°C.

Comment: @mia What I meant is that temperature will also vary along the pipe (fluid as well as pipe), because as the water goes through and heats up, the temperature difference driving local heat transfer will go down. Pipe wall should not have the same temperature as water at the outlet, because as the temperature difference goes down, the heat transfer gets almost negligible, so for a pipe with finite length, you should always end up with some temperature difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with your calculations. The temperature rise should be about 10.7 °C.

The stainless steel aspect is mostly irrelevant other than it should ease any worries about rust, etc., affecting the result.

Now, what's the answer to the other bits? I'd have to do some more thinking and research before I could answer confidently.

Comment: As for the rest, my thinking process is that since the DC current and water inlet temperature are constants, the pipe would be heated up to 20°C by the water and up an additional 10.7°C by the constant current.
Got confused when I tried to use these values to get the LMTD, so I tried to use the heat transfer coefficient formula using heat flux over temperature difference between the pipe and the fluid. So the heat flux is 22500/(pi*0.016*2.5) = 179049.31 W/m^2, and that divided by the temp difference 10.7 C is 16744 W/m^2 C.

Comment: For the second part of the question, I think I should use the heat transfer formula Q = h*A*LMTD. I’m not quite sure if the “temperature difference of the convective heat transfer in the pipe” part of the problem is referring to the 10.7 C bit or to the LMTD though.